# Is it OK to link other people's answers?

Tags: discussion

I was on [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/44680/showcase-your-language-one-vote-at-a-time-experimental-challenge) page, and I noticed some entries for the list in the description were missing. Is it OK for me to link these entries, or do I have to ask permission from the posters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go ahead and add them. I don't see why they object, seeing they've submitted their answers publicly (under the CC BY-SA licence) and anyone anywhere on the internet could link to them.

Also, you don't have enough rep for single-handed edits yet, so if you suggest the edit it goes through the review queue anyway. In theory, you don't need to ask for permission on meta. If you've made a "wrong" edit, someone will reject it and (hopefully) give you a reason for the rejection.

You might also want to [join us in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte) for simple questions like this. (Nothing wrong with asking on meta, but chat might be quicker, and if people think it's worth getting a more official consensus you can still post it on meta.)